# This context undefined in the parent class

Tags: typescript

I came across the following scenario:

```
abstract class Base {
    public _obj = { name: 'Test' }

    print1() {
        console.log(this._obj)
    }

    print2() {
        console.log(this)
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    print2() { // overriding
        // do some stuff
        console.log(this._obj)
    }
}

function test(cb: any) {
    cb()
}

const obj = new Child()
obj.print1() // ok!
obj.print2() // ok!
test(obj.print1) // undefined
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.8.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=17#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gFAIkIAOAriMgJawID6A9iAFYIC8BCAdsALY4AXAgDkAFRyRRCAL6FipMlBo8IARgAUASgKLSpWEx5gmyHADpkTAOaaIACxpgLzNtv1yFB5aogAmHT0DAyMTM0trO0dnDwN5eUIUNAwAYSdkABMEHAAPCBweTIxsMDwiHxU1QN18BAB6eoQmADccKBVM1RtPA0aETKYEU0FhiAoAMwnew2NTcytbeycXN1Y40gSFCYoeeBpjBALITVgQEWAeAE9azzOdQkSwyGa2Tl4cAHcEdJosh5YrAsvjUWl0-SYAGsAISEQHAqoBIIQmGEY4QTTwkEabRAA)

If I print the `this` it will be undefined.
Why when I pass the function as a parameter I lose the `this` context?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why when I pass the function as a parameter I lose the this context?

That is how `this` works in JavaScript. From your code the issue is highlighted:

```
function test(cb: any) {
    cb() // `this` is undefined
}
```

## Fix

Simplest fix would be to pass in a function that does not depend on `this` e.g.: `test(() => obj.print1())`

## Complete code:

```
abstract class Base {
    public _obj = { name: 'Test' }

    print1() {
        console.log(this._obj)
    }

    print2() {
        console.log(this)
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    print2() { // overriding
        // do some stuff
        console.log(this._obj)
    }
}

function test(cb: any) {
    cb() // `this` is undefined
}

const obj = new Child()
obj.print1() // ok!
obj.print2() // ok!
test(() => obj.print1())
```

## Additional Resources

[I also have a video on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FR9mt_ZO2HA)

Comment: Now i'm using bind function. `test(obj.print1.bind(obj))` It works better for mer